# Sending emails with mailgun and Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4, mailgun

I am trying to learn how to send emails using Mailgun in Laravel.  When I try to send the email I get a timeout that says: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
The application times out here:

```
$line = fgets($this->_out);
```

I have a route that activates when I click a button on my email page:

```
Route::post('/email', 'MainController@sendEmail');
```

Here is my controller function (replaced my email for privacy reasons):

```
    public function sendEmail() {
        $data = [
            'title'=>'Email'
        ];
        Mail::send('emails.hello', $data, function($message) {
            $message->from('example@gmail.com', 'Example Person');
            $message->to('example@gmail.com')->subject('we made it');
        });
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
```

Any ideas on what I may do be doing wrong?

Comment: How did you configured Laravel to use Mailgun? Do you have your domain set in Mailgun? Did you created your credentials to send mails via Mailgun smtp? http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#credentials

Answer (score 2):

This generally happens if the SMTP port used in the app/config/mail.php config file is not opened by your hosting provider. Please check and ask them to open the port. This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sending emails through mailgun could not be simpler, just add the API package, publish and update the config and use the custom facade to send them (changing Mail::send() to Mailgun::send())

You can find the package here: http://packalyst.com/packages/package/vtalbot/mailgun

I know this doesn't really address the error your getting (would need more information to help with that), but using the package does simplify the whole thing!